# Select only elements of a list containing tables with two columns in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing 10000 elements, each element contains a table with different amount of columns, an example list (with less elements) is shown below. Is there a way to only select the elements with two columns in an extra list but only showing the numbers and not the characters (as in the example `[[1]]`)?

```
$`1`

  a   g 
 41 498 

$`2`

  c   t  g
 40 499  1

$`3`

  a   c   g   t 
 28  36 466   9 

$`4`

  t 
539
```

Expected output would be:

```
$`1`

41 498
```

Do you know any solution?

Comment: Do you have a `table` object or `data.frame` or just named vector as `list` element

Comment: it's just named vector, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to create a logical vector to subset the `list`, then loop over the subset `list` and `unname` or convert to a `vector` with `as.vector` or `unlist` (if it is a data.frame)

```
lapply(lst1[lengths(lst1) == 2], unname)
#$`1`
#[1]  41 498
```

---

If these are `data.frame` in a `list`

```
lapply(lst1[sapply(lst1, ncol) == 2], unlist, use.names = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(`1` = c(a = 41, g = 498), `2` = c(c = 40, t = 499, g = 1
), `3` = c(a = 28, c = 36, g = 466, t = 9), `4` = c(t = 539))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm using lapply to find which lengths are equal to 2, then indexing.

let L be your list

`L[lapply(L,length) == 2]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

- `subset` with `lengths`

```
> subset(lst,lengths(lst)==2)
$`1`
  a   g
 41 498
```

- `Filter`

```
> Filter(function(x) length(x)==2,lst)
$`1`
  a   g
 41 498
```

**Data**

```
> dput(lst)
list(`1` = c(a = 41, g = 498), `2` = c(c = 40, t = 499, g = 1
), `3` = c(a = 28, c = 36, g = 466, t = 9), `4` = c(t = 539))
```